# Leer excel con gran cantidad de columnas en C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Hola estimados desarrolladores, tengo un pequeño problema, resulta que estoy leyendo hojas excel en un programa de consola y me toco un excel que tiene una gran cantidad de columnas (Hasta la columna ABT) y mi dataset excel sólo lee hasta la columna WZ y nose como lograr que lea la hoja completa sin dejar ninguna columna fuera. tengo que hacerlo en OLEDB por temas de licencia de mi cliente.
Acá el código

```
OleDbConnection Econ;
Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
string qTotal = string.Format("Select * from[Sheet1$]");
string qTotalvalores = string.Format("Select * from[Sheet1$A12:ABT755]");
OleDbCommand ETotal = new OleDbCommand(qTotal, Econ);
OleDbCommand Etotal2 = new OleDbCommand(qTotalvalores, Econ);

termino = termino + 1;

Econ.Open(); //al procesar el archivo n° 120 //Se cae la conexion en Econ.Open();

// Creacion de Dataset para cada uno de los contructores
DataSet dsTotal = new DataSet();
DataSet dsTotal2 = new DataSet();
OleDbDataAdapter odaTotal = new OleDbDataAdapter(qTotal, Econ);
OleDbDataAdapter odaTotal2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(qTotalvalores, Econ);

Econ.Close();
```

Comment: son mas de 256 columnas? creo que hay un tope...

Comment: Si muchas mas de 256 columnas

Comment: Por lo menos la mayoria de las db estan topeadas en la cantidad de columnas que pueden tener (en gral 256).. no me extrañaria que al dataset le pasara lo mismo... aunque no tengo info al respecto.. fijate por ahi...

Comment: No evaluaste usar una libreria basada en open xml, como ser ClosedXml https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Using-Tables  con esta podrias definir el acceso a una tabla y usar el AsTable()

Comment: Lo evaluamos pero por temas del proyecto no es posible, quieren todo basado en Microsoft

Comment: open xml se basa en las librerias de microsoft, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet closedxml es solo un wrapper para hacerlo mas simple

Answer (score -1):

No se puede leer más de 256 columnas con OLED, está limitado.
Una opción es partir la tabla en varios rangos de columnas y luego los consultas por rangos como Select * From RangeName

La otra opción es utilizar ExcelDataReader DLL
Es una biblioteca de código abierto utilizada para leer archivos de Microsoft Excel en .NET
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/

PD. Respondo como respuesta porque con mi puntuación todavía no puedo hacer comentarios, solo responder. Confío en que no me penalicen

Comment: Hola Jose. Dices que respondes como respuesta. Eso es correcto. Comentar en respuesta es lo incorrecto. Has de esperara a tener 50 de rep para **ganar el privilegio**. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias lois6b. Pero no entiendo una cosa. Si el usuario seleccionó mi respuesta como la elegida y gané 15 puntos, por qué ahora he perdido 20. Qué he hecho mal? y como he perdido esos puntos? Quién los ha quitado?

Comment: @JoseDEV la respuesta ya no está aceptada por lo que se te restaron 15 puntos... esos 5 extra no los veo reflejados en tu perfil>reputacion. Un saludo